# Can I keep multiple save files for the same play-through? (Xbox 360)

Tags: xbox-360, far-cry-3

I like to keep several save files as I play through games just in case something goes wrong (corrupted file, missed something important, etc.).  When I started Far Cry 3 (Xbox 360) I was disappointed to see only 3 save game slots I could choose from.  After trying to perform a manual save during the game, I am even more disappointed that it seems to simply save over the same one file with every save.

Is there any way to create multiple save files for the same play-through from within the game?  I suppose I could always go to the memory from the dashboard and copy my save files from there to create an archive, but that is a lot more effort then I thought it would take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game does not give you the direct oppurtunity to have multiple save files for one playthrough, so you will have to go to the "system settings" -> "memory units" -> "memory device holding your saves" on your xbox and then copy the savegame you want onto a different device (e.g. USB stick).
 That way you have a backup if the savegame corrupts.
 It is a lot of effort but the only way to do it without a modded xbox, sorry.

There are 3 missable things: The achievements "Unheard" and "Fully Inked", and the alternative ending. Everything else can be done after you played the story to its end, as you will still be on the islands.

Comment: There are two missable achievements: [Unheard](http://www.trueachievements.com/a171066/unheard-achievement.htm?showguides=1) and [Fully Inked](http://www.trueachievements.com/a171081/fully-inked-achievement.htm?showguides=1)

Comment: @Weezle Thanks for the heads-up. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haft to pause the game and go to save game. You can only do it once per play through because each play through has an autosave and a manual save. So make it count. I prefer that you do it towards the end when they tell you that their isn't any going back. Choose no then save it. After that, you can choose to go to the point of no return and you'll know why I told you to save it before. Enjoy.